# How do I turn the json string to datatable?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, datatable

I am trying to parse google's API response json formatted string into datatable.

I tried using `using Newtonsoft.Json;` and doing this:

```
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(textBox1.Text);
        DataTable tester = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.ToString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

I am getting this error: `Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.`

When I run the string throught JSONLint, it is saying that the string is Valid.

`here is json:` http://jsfiddle.net/q4XqQ/

Comment: That would mean your JSON is invalid.

Comment: Can you post the json string you get the error?

Comment: run your json string through http://jsonlint.com/ and validate it

Comment: it is saying valid json; I added link to json text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up parsing json string and writing some regex that worked fine.